# Security better between WPA/WPA2 and AP Login Webpage

Tags: wireless

I silly wonder if we can stand outside and sniff password login webpage in protocol HTTPS or not? And attacker can brute force the WPA or WPA2 but if they change  AP:set non-password and redirect client when click SSID, use a defaut webpage to login Acess Point with database stored all user enter or supply user the username and password.They can brute-force WPA/WPA2 password but I wonder if attack can crack password on web login with protocol HTTPS and firewall or S.A blocking brute force attack,prevent automatic login by captcha.

So what is better security with router wireless configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't the easiest to understand, but I take it you're concerned about the security of the router admin pages on your device. There are ways of compromising the security of HTTPS connections, such as performing MITM attacks (made much easier by manufacturer's tendencies to use self-signed certificates).

However, this is rarely the easiest way of getting in. Recently Netgear, one of the largest router manufacturers, revealed a serious security weakness in the software of some of its products, that can be exploited without even being connected to the network in question. Essentially the attack revolves around a piece of software running on the router that does not correctly verify its input (your credentials/the action). You can read about that here: http://www.computerworld.com/article/3149555/security/an-unpatched-vulnerability-exposes-netgear-routers-to-hacking.html

If you're dead-serious about protecting it, then the best way of doing this is to **turn off the web interface**. Failing that the next best thing to do is to use network segregation to control from where on your network the configuration  services can be accessed. I do this with a Cisco access point; the wireless users join a different VLAN than the configuration service, and the router refuses to route between the management VLAN and the wireless VLAN, thus preventing them from getting at the configuration portal without using some form of jump-box. This, however, is not a feature available on most consumer-grade routers that I have encountered.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer , I'll read it. If someone is Networking Administrator and works with Netgear routers. I'll share them.

Comment: Agree that leaving the configuration interface off if possible is best. Some devices such as the excellent Ubiquiti AP's (which are the same price as decent consumer-grade AP's) are able to use a separate application to manage them. Restricting management to the wired interface where possible is always going to be more secure.